# Decimal parsing differences on separate environments

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio, locale, openxml

Evening,

I'm bashing my head against a wall with the following problem:

- I'm loading numbers from cells from a `Number` column with `size=16`
  and `decimal places = 2` inside a`dBase III .dbf` file.
- These numbers, when viewed with a `DbfViewer` appear as: `12345.12`, where there is no thousands separator and the decimal
  separator is `.`.
- I parse the number from the cell in the database using `decimal.parse(val)`.
- I do stuff with that number.
- I am using the `ClosedXML` library to paste the number into an `.xlsx` Excel file cell with the following formula: `"=R[-1]C * 100/" & val` where `val` is the value I obtained from the `dBaseIII` database file. This is done with the following statements:

  - `Dim formula as String = "=R[-1]C * 100/" & project.TotalIncome(i)`
  - `cell.FormulaR1C1 = formula`.
- I am using two programming environments:

  1. A `Windows 8.1` machine with `Visual Studio 2013 Community` and `Office 2010`.
  2. A `Windows 8.1` machine with `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate` and `Office 2013`.
- I have made sure that both environments have the same `Language, Date, Time and Number` format, both for Windows and Office.

When I build and execute the program from the `Option 1 Environment`, everything pastes fine inside the Excel file. I navigate to the cell containing the formula, and whether or not the `value` obtained had decimal places, the formula is there.

**However**, If I build and execute the program from the `Option 2 Environment`, I get a:

- `Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part`
- `Removed Records: Formula from /xl/calcChain.xml part (calculation properties)`

I tried adding a breakpoint in `Environment 2`, opening the `Locals` window and editing those `values` which had decimal places and everything worked as intended, whereas when I use `Environment 1` I have no trouble whatsoever when the `value` has decimal places.

I have tried the following (in `Environment 2`):

```
Dim nfi As NumberFormatInfo = New CultureInfo("es-ES", False).NumberFormat
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
value = Decimal.Parse(row("VALUECOL"), nfi)
```

also:

`value = Decimal.Parse(row("VALUECOL"), New CultureInfo("es-ES"))`

To no avail.

I have opened the XML file containing the Excel Sheet info in `Environment 2` and found this:

```
<x:c r="L101" s="41">
    <x:f>L100 * 100/57125,71</x:f>
</x:c>
```

Whereas the definitions for the same XML file created by the `Environment 1` has the following cell value:

```
<x:c r="L101" s="41">
    <x:f>L100 * 100/57125.71</x:f>
</x:c>
```

So, is it a Visual Studio Locale thing (which both have the same, as far as I can see), or am I missing something else?

---

**EDIT:** Printing out the current Locale with:

`Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)`

yields the same `es-ES` on both `Environment 1` and `Environment 2`.

---

**EDIT 2:** 
Taken from: [Microsoft Office XML formats. Defective by design.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20246/Microsoft-Office-XML-formats-Defective-by-design)

> To save them time, Microsoft chose to store XML using the US English
>   locale regardless of all settings above. [...]
>
> Also, for Excel **formulas**, it means the formula names are **US English**
>   formula names, [...] it implies you are willing to work with US English
>   function names (plus **US English separators**, ...).

So basically it all boils down (I believe) to a pre localisation of the `decimal` value into the `Excel XML` taking into account *something, somewhere*.

In `Environment 2`, any other (non-formula) value I write to the Excel file appears in the `XML` as an `en-US` localised value (i.e. `12345.12`). Most of them brought in by a `dataTable` import. However, since writing a formula requires the input of a string, and Visual Studio applies locale settings to said string, it ends up as `12345,12` in the `Excel XML`, which results in the previously mentioned errors.

So, **what on earth** is Visual Studio taking from `Environment 1` that is **different** from `Environment 2`? All possible UI localisation options are exactly the same in both machines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even know if this qualifies as an answer since I still have no clue about where's the localisation variable that `Environment 1` has different from `Environment 2`.

However, It seems Visual Studio -*when using different localisations*- deals **internally** with de-localised `decimal` variables, but with localised `string` variables. Even when checking the `locals` panel during debugging, the value of a `decimal` number stored in a `dictionary` entry will appear as its localised version on the `keyValuePair` entry, and as a de-localised `en-US` value when expanded:

[image: Different localisations depending on representation]

Hence, when outputting a `dataTable` **as a whole** to the Excel file, it's written onto the XML as `en-US` values. On the other hand, when outputting a formula (a.k.a. a `string`) it pours over the localised version of the associated `decimal` value.

Conclusion: When dealing with Office files in localised systems, just write the data as de-localised (i.e. `en-US`) and let the software localise it for you.

Ended up doing the following dirty patch:

```
Dim formula As String = "=R[-1]C * 100/" & project.TotalIncome(i).ToString().Replace(",", ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before, and found that there was a different dll file in my project references. The dll's were named the same, I only noticed because of a file size difference. Once I manually linked to the same one on both Dev machines, I got the expected results.

Like I said, my issue was different... But it did also involve excel files, and I did have Excel 2010 on one Dev machine and 2013 on the other.

Comment: I have checked both external `dll`s i use (`ClosedXML.dll` v.0.69.1.0 and `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` v.2.0.5022.0) and are both the exact same size. Thanks for the input, though! :)